Is it possible to have repetitions within an inner macro_rules defined by another macro_rules in Rust?
I'd like to write a macro that defines macros that define enums with attrs, something like this:
macro_rules! define_enum_definer {
  {
    $($variant: ident => $t: ty,)+
  }
  => {
    macro_rules! define_enum {
      ($(#[$attrs:meta])*$name: ident($container: ident)) => {
        $(#[$attrs])*
        enum $name {
          $($variant($container<$t>),)+
        }
      };
    }
  };
}

define_enum_definer! { I32 => i32, I64 => i64, }
define_enum!(
  #[derive(Clone, Debug)]
  #[non_exhaustive]
  DynTypedVec(Vec)
);

fn main() {
  let x = DynTypedVec::I32(vec![1, 2, 3]);
  println!("{:?}", x);
}

But this fails with
error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |       ($(#[$attrs:meta])*$name: ident($container: ident)) => {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

It's trying to repeat the syntax variable in the outer macro, but I need it to repeat for the inner macro. I tried to escape the inner repeats with $dollar, but that too fails with
error: missing fragment specifier
  --> src/main.rs:12:8
   |
12 |       ($dollar(#[$attrs:meta])*$name: ident($container: ident)) => {
   |        ^^^^^^^
...
22 | define_inner_macro! { Foo => i32, Bar => i64, }
   | ----------------------------------------------- in this macro invocation

Is there a way around this, or is my only recourse to use procedural macros?

The escaping works this way: you need, in the outer macro's declaration, take $dollar:tt (probably at the beginning) which you will fill when calling it when $, and then, in the inner macro, when you want to write $ you write $dollar instead. E.g. $name:ident becomes $dollar name:ident.

You can use the trick here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35853#issuecomment-415993963. I'll just copy their code below; adapting it is simple enough.

macro_rules! with_dollar_sign {
    ($($body:tt)*) => {
        macro_rules! __with_dollar_sign { $($body)* }
        __with_dollar_sign!($);
    }
}

macro_rules! make_println {
    ($name:ident, $fmt:expr) => {
        with_dollar_sign! {
            ($d:tt) => {
                macro_rules! $name {
                    ($d($d args:expr),*) => {           // (1)
                        println!($fmt, $d($d args),*);  // (2)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

make_println!(my_dbg, "{:?}");

fn main() {
    my_dbg!(42);
}



This mechanism allows one to pseudo-escape the $ by passing it as a token to the inner macro, and does solve the problem.

You have to escape every $ that's only in the inner macro by doubling it up:
#![feature(macro_metavar_expr)]
macro_rules! define_enum_definer {
  {
    $($variant: ident => $t: ty,)+
  }
  => {
    macro_rules! define_enum {
      ($$(#[$$attrs:meta])* $$name:ident ( $$container:ident )) => {
        $$(#[$$attrs])*
        enum $$name {
          $($variant($$container<$t>),)+
        }
      };
    }
  };
}

Since for the time being that depends on the unstable feature macro_metavavar_expr if you can't or don't want to use a nightly compiler  you'll have to use a workaround for the time being. For example like this:
macro_rules! define_enum_definer {
  ($($variant: ident => $t: ty,)+) => { define_enum_definer!{@internal ($) $($variant => $t,)*} };
  (@internal ($d:tt) $($variant: ident => $t: ty,)+) => {
    macro_rules! define_enum {
      ($d (#[$d attrs:meta])* $d name:ident ( $d container:ident )) => {
        $d (#[$d attrs])*
        enum $d name {
          $($variant($d container<$t>),)+
        }
      };
    }
  };
}

